# Selecionar data através de datepicker

Tags: php, datepicker

Devs blz?

No meu formulário preciso incluir um campo para selecionar data, quero utilizar um datepicker bootstrap ou similar. Trata-se de um sistema de agendamento onde faço uma consulta ao banco de dados para retornar os horários disponíveis para o dia selecionado.

A questão é que estou fazendo essa consulta com select...Minha dúvida é como eu posso colocar                     um calendário na entrada do select para fazer essa consulta, pelo que sei só consigo chamar um calendário com input type='data'

```
    <label class="label">
    <span>Selecione um dia:</span>
    <select name="appointment_schedule_id" class="horarios">
        <option selected disabled value="">Nenhum Selecionado</option>
        <?php
        $read->readFull("SELECT 

                            *
        
                            FROM schedule s 
                            WHERE s.schedule_status IS NULL 
                                AND s.schedule_tstamp >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                            GROUP BY s.schedule_ref
                            ORDER BY s.schedule_tstamp ASC");
                            

        $schedules = ($read->getResult() ? $read->getResult() : null);

        if (!empty($schedules)) {
            foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
                $schedule = (object) $schedule;
                echo "<option value='{$schedule->schedule_id}'>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($schedule->schedule_tstamp)) . "</option>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

Não sei se deu para entender, resumindo preciso que no select do código acima ao clicar possa estar abrindo um calendário para que possa escolher data para agendamento.

Comment: Cara já precisei fazer isso uma vez, no meu caso usei o Datepicker do Jquery UI, e carregava os dados do banco via requisição ajax e inseria no calendário, no caso do Datepicker do Jquery UI tem como mostrar ele na tela sem precisar de um input.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: Opa então na sua opinião vc acha que eu deveria tirar ele select e fazer a busca ao banco de dados via ajax?

Comment: No meu ver seria uma boa opção, ao selecionar a data você usaria o próprio gatilho do Datepicker para buscar via ajax no banco e preencher seu select com os horários disponíveis para o dia selecionado.

Comment: Vou estar tentando essa busca via ajax, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @GnomoEscalate cara teria algum exemplo desse select ajax